# After updating Android Studio, my project is giving an error: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm new to Android programming. Today, after I updating Android Studio, my project (which was working) started giving an error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0.
     Required by:
         POSv2:app:unspecified
```

Why is this happening? Did anyone experience something like this? I really don't know why this is happening.

So far the only solution is re-download the SDK, so i will create new folder and fresh download all the SDK there. I will update when im done!

**update:** I solve this issue by creating new folder, and fresh download the sdk there, then target the sdk folder to that folder.

Comment: update your google repository from SDK Manager.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: @PrathapBadavath the issue is appear after i update the google repository from SDK Manager

Comment: @sunilsunny i tried both, still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Android SDK Manager (separately or from Android Studio itself) and make sure you have the API 23 SDK and the "Support Repository" downloaded (scroll to the bottom).

If you want to see what versions you do have available, then the directory is at

```
ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
```

Otherwise, that error is strange because you should be able to have Gradle download that library if it is missing, so best guess is that the SDK libraries got updated and/or cleaned.

Comment: I have the API 23, not sure how its happens.. and then i open dependencies tab on project structure and i remove the library dependencies, and it gives another error, i dunt know how to get it again

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting anything from the UI. You can edit the `build.gradle` file directly for that.

Comment: i already revert the changes from my back up, i dont know what is wrong

Comment: i checked the folder, i have 23.3.0, actually i have from 18.0.0 until 24.2.1, i got SDK libraries updated

Comment: Also, i tried to create new project, empty one, when i build, its have the same error

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle to the question? And a screenshot of the SDK manager? Something is off

Comment: I solve this by re-download all the sdk, i update it above, thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't think you needed "all the sdk", but that's good

Comment: ya, agree. But for newbie it the easiest solution i think